# I am trying to merge jwt to my code but i am getting module error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jwt

I am trying to add token mechanism to the below code. I tried many approaches but below one seems to be simpler way to achieve jwt. But when I ran the code got module error at `from security import authenticate, identity`

I also tried by creating separate requirements.txt but it doesn't work.

Here is my code

```
from flask import request
from flask import Flask
#from jsonify.convert import jsonify
from flask import jsonify
from pyspark.shell import spark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, DoubleType, BooleanType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, array_contains
import json
#from flask_jwt_extended import create_access_token
#from flask_jwt_extended import get_jwt_identity
#from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required
#from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager, jwt_required, create_access_token
import base64
from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required
from flask import Flask
from flask_jwt import JWT
from security import authenticate, identity

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "righdata"  # Make this long, random, and secret in a real app!
jwt = JWT(app, authenticate, identity)
app.config['JWT_ALGORITHM'] = 'HS512'
#jwt = JWTManager(app)
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("DX_STATS").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
spark.sql("SHOW TABLES").show()

class User(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = id
        self.username = "abc"
        self.password = "password"

    def __str__(self):
        return "User(id='%s')" % self.id

users = [
    User(1, 'abc', 'password'),
]

username_table = {u.self.username: u for u in users}
userid_table = {u.id: u for u in users}

def authenticate():
    username = "abc"
    password = "password"
    user = username_table.get(username, None)
    if user and safe_str_cmp(user.password.encode('utf-8'), password.encode('utf-8')):
        return user

def identity(payload):
    user_id = payload['identity']
    return userid_table.get(user_id, None)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret_key'

jwt = JWT(app, authenticate, identity)

# if __name__ == '__main__':
#     app.run()
@app.route('/analyze', methods=["POST"])
@jwt_required()
def analyze():
    print(request.is_json)
    content = request.get_json()
    print(content)
    dir = content["preview"]
    print(dir)
    sql = "select * from " + tablename + " limit " + str(content["previewCount"])
    df = spark.sql(sql)
    data = df.toPandas()
    stats = data.describe(include=['object'])
    df2 = data.isnull().sum()
    notnull = data.notnull().sum()
    zero = (data == 0).sum(axis=0)
    nonzero = (data != 0).sum(axis=0)
    null_result = json.loads(df2.to_json(orient="index"))
    not_null = json.loads(notnull.to_json(orient="index"))
    stats_result = json.loads(stats.to_json(orient='index'))
    zero_result = json.loads(zero.to_json(orient="index"))
    non_zero = json.loads(nonzero.to_json(orient='index'))
    
    return json.dumps(stats_result, indent=4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)  # host = "0.0.0.0",port = specific port0
```

And I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .security import authenticate, identity
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.security'; '__main__' is not a package
^C
[1]+  Exit 1                  python new.py
$ python3 -m security
/bin/python3: No module named security
$~/myproject$
```

Actual Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "new.py", line 19, in 
from security import authenticate, identity
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'security'

And I also got below errors:

Error-1:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
flask-jwt 0.3.2 requires PyJWT<1.5.0,>=1.4.0, but you have pyjwt 2.1.0 which is incompatible.
flask-appbuilder 3.3.0 requires Flask-JWT-Extended<4,>=3.18, but you have flask-jwt-extended 4.2.1 which is incompatible.
flask-appbuilder 3.3.0 requires PyJWT<2.0.0,>=1.7.1, but you have pyjwt 2.1.0 which is incompatible.
```

Error-2:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
flask-jwt 0.3.2 requires PyJWT<1.5.0,>=1.4.0, but you have pyjwt 1.7.1 which is incompatible.
```

These are always installing the latest versions. How can I install the specific versions.

Comment: the error says `from .security` but your code has `from security`. Have you checked your code?

Comment: Yea i tried keeping .security also but the actual error is this
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 19, in <module>
    from security import authenticate, identity
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'security'

Comment: Can you show where have you placed security.py

Comment: I dont have security.py file i followed below link : 
https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JWT/